# How to pass implicit reference from constructor

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit

I have the following code:

```
class myClass(someObject:Option[SomeThing]){

  def doSomeThing(a:Int,b:Int)(implicit someOtherOption:Option[SomeThing]) = ??? 
}
```

I would like to pass `someObject` from constructor to `doSomething` method.

I can do it by making `implicit` reference inside a class

```
implicit val someImplictObject = someObject
```

but this way looks ugly. I guess, I can use `implicitly` method but I can't find correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default value for someOtherOption this way:

```
def doSomeThing(a:Int, b:Int)
   (implicit someOtherOption:Option[SomeThing] = someObject) = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to pass it when calling the method or when defining it? In the first case you just need `doSomething(a, b)(someObject)`. In the second, you can write

```
def doSomeThing(a:Int,b:Int) = { // no someOtherOption parameter
  implicit val someImplictObject = someObject
  ...
}
```

without making `someObject` avaialable implicitly to the entire class.